# Django: Problems with serving static files with non ascii names

Tags: python, django

I've moved my django application from one server to another, and spotted strange bug with media after it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

 File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-
packages/Django-1.1.1-py2.5.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 92, in get_response
   response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

 File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/Django-1.1.1-py2.5.egg/django/views/static.py", line 51, in serve
   if os.path.isdir(fullpath):

 File "/usr/lib/python2.5/posixpath.py", line 195, in isdir
   st = os.stat(path)

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 44-46: ordinal not in range(128)
```

The image I am trying to access actually have Cyrillic symbols in the name, but it didn't made a problem on previous environment

Thanks,
Oleg

Comment: What are the differences between servers: OS, python version...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, don't have Django serve your static files.  See this: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/

Comment: Lets stick to solving the problem.

Comment: @ashchristopher: The problem may very well be using Django to do something it isn't well suited to do.  Let the web server serve the static files, and the problem may go away.

Comment: Its reasonable to want this working in a test server environment. Particularily to make it portable. Although this is a good, 'just get on with it' solution

Answer (score 0):

In Django documentation it's written that this may be connected to Apache settings (discovered via [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/django-users/LVzSXVy6TSE/AZEp90hQiRoJ)).

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/deployment/modpython/#if-you-get-a-unicodeencodeerror

"Ensure that the environment used to start Apache is configured to accept non-ASCII file names. If your environment is not correctly configured, you will trigger UnicodeEncodeError exceptions when calling functions like os.path() on filenames that contain non-ASCII characters.

To avoid these problems, the environment used to start Apache should contain settings analogous to the following:

```
export LANG='en_US.UTF-8'
export LC_ALL='en_US.UTF-8'
```

Consult the documentation for your operating system for the appropriate syntax and location to put these configuration items; /etc/apache2/envvars is a common location on Unix platforms. Once you have added these statements to your environment, restart Apache."

P.S. My current hosting technical support is very slow, neither have I access to Apache settings. That's why currently I have to resort to django static serve. My site isn't too frequently visited and I've no other choice even though I know it's not optimal.